# Compound Preposition?

Tags: grammar

She rushed home ahead of the storm.

Is "ahead of" a compound preposition in the sentence.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it's not a compound prep. The PP "ahead of the storm" consists of "ahead" as head followed by the PP "of the storm" as complement of the head.

Answer (score 2):

*She rushed home ahead of the storm.*

No, "ahead of" is not a compound prep. The PP "ahead of the storm" consists of "ahead" as head followed by the PP "of the storm" as complement of the head.

The verb "rushed" has "home" as its complement, and "ahead of the storm" is an adjunct in clause structure.

Note that *of* PP's most commonly function as complement of a preceding noun, though in this case  "ahead" is not a noun but a preposition which selects "of" as head of its complement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is "ahead of" a compound preposition in the sentence.

The answer depends on which grammar you follow.

To me:

**home** is an adverb = to her house (also known as [an adverbial objective](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbial-Nouns.htm#Time) and seen as a noun...)

**ahead** is an adverb that modifies "of the storm". (We could replace "ahead" with "in front")

**of the storm** is a prepositional phrase modifying "rushed".

Others, who believe in other grammars may disagree.

Comment: The analogous 'She raced to the hospital behind the ambulance' certainly provides an argument that 'ahead of' is a two-word preposition.